# Android: convert a url sent from a server into a textview, such that on click on that textview the app opens that url in a browser window?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, dynamic-data

I'm recieving an url like "http://www.msn.com" from the server. I want to display a textview which says click here, on clicking it the url should open in a browser.
how to take the url and make a textview link for it and on click open a website.

Comment: the url that is coming from the server is in 2 formats , one is like this  "<a target=\"_black\" href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Test Survey Question</a>"  and other is like http://www.msn.com.   so could you also suggest me a generalised format to handle both the kinds of response.

Comment: i already have a way to handle the first kind of response, please could you tell me how to handle the second one.

Comment: if you need partially clickable textview .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140815/partially-clickable-textview-and-different-text-colors-for-the-text-android/34147019#34147019

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

Comment: i want to know how to handle the url "www.msn.com" and how it should be set to a textview.

Comment: you dont need to set the link to textview. just do onclickListner for textview(clickhere )  in that write code to open the link you got from server

Comment: i dont know in which format im getting the url from the server it may either be embedded in an anchor tag like this "<a target=\"_black\" href=\"yahoo.com\">Test Survey Question</a>"  or just a simple url like "http://www.msn.com"  so there has to be a method to check the format and then convert it into a link and open it in a browser. how to write a generalised method to check the format?

Answer (score 0):

Since your getting the data from server in JSON format I hope definitely you will use the data in any adapter and data gets sent to each and every view. So implement an on-click listener inside the display adapter and whenever u click that text view pass that URL got from the server into that view. Then it will open the required URL in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Either You can use `android:autoLink="web"` for that `TextView` and setting text as `URL`

Or You set `onClick` for that link and add following Intent in onClick

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent );
```